# Selenium: MoveByOffset doesn't work after ClickAndHold

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to mark text on a webpage in C# with Selenium ChromeDriver. This is my code:

```
var webElement = driver.GetElement(IdentifierValue, IdentifierType);
var actions = new Actions(driver);            
actions.MoveToElement(webElement,
                startX,
                startY).ClickAndHold().MoveByOffset(offsetX, offsetY).Release().Perform();
```

It doesn't work, the MoveByOffset action doesn't seem to be executed. It seems to be a problem with the combination of `ClickAndHold()` and `MoveByOffset()`. 
When I execute `MoveByOffset()` and `ClickAndHold()` separated it behaves like expected. For example like this:

```
actions1.MoveToElement(webElement, startX, startY).Click().Perform();
Thread.Sleep(1000);
actions2.MoveByOffset(offsetX, offsetY).Perform();
Thread.Sleep(1000);
actions3.Click().Perform();
```

And this:

```
actions1.MoveToElement(webElement, startX, startY).ClickAndHold().Perform();
```

I didn't find anything about this on the net. So did anyone experienced something similar or has a solution to this problem?

Comment: Is that a text input element?

Comment: Yes it is a text input element.